# How to resolve Overfull on the table?

Tags: tables, compiling, warnings

When I run my code, I get : `Overfull \hbox (31.04974pt too wide) in alignement at lines 287--347`

```
\documentclass
    \chapter{ Présentation Générale}

    \label{chap1}
\minitoc
\newpage
   \section{Méthodologie du travail }
Suivre une méthodologie de travail est une première assurance pour produire des logiciels et des applications de qualité qui répondent aux besoins des utilisateurs tout en respectant la contrainte du temps en assurant une optimisation du produit.\\
En effet, il existe plusieurs méthodologies de développement parmi lesquelles nous citons les approches classiques caractérisées par un processus de développement linéaire dont ses phases principales sont recueillir les besoins, définir le produit, le développer et le tester avant de le livrer. \\
Il s'agit ici de prévoir des phases séquentielles et des plans détaillés basées sur des exigences stables dès le début du projet.

\subsection{Étude comparative entre ces méthodologies }
Le tableau ci-dessous dégage les différences entre les méthodes de développement susmentionnées :

\newpage

\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
& \textbf{Principes }& \textbf{Points forts} & \textbf{Points faibles} \\
\hline
\begin{center}
\textbf{Modèle en Cascade}
\end{center}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Les étapes se terminent à des dates précises par la production de documents ou logiciels.
\item Processus linéaire.
\item Les résultats de d’étapes sont examinées attentivement avant de passer à l’étape suivante.
\end{itemize}
& 
\begin{itemize}
\item Facile à comprendre et à utiliser.
\item Les limites de chaque étape sont visibles.
\item Vision globale du projet au cours de développement.
\end{itemize}

& 
\begin{itemize}
\item Tous les besoins doivent être bien spécifiés au départ.
\item Difficulté de retour en arrière aux cas des anomalies.
\item L’intégration n’a lieu qu’à la fin du cycle.
\end{itemize}\\

\hline
\begin{center}
\textbf{Modèle en V}
\end{center} 
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Le développement de test et du logiciel sont effectuées de manière synchrone.
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Met l’accent sur les tests et la validation et donc accroît la qualité.
\item Chaque livrable doit être testable.
\item Facile à utiliser et à planifier.
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Le processus n’est pas itératif.
\item Ne gère pas les activités parallèles.
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
&
\begin{itemize}
\item  Avec toute décomposition doit être décrite la recomposition.
\item Toute description d’un composant est accompagnée de tests qui assurent leurs correspondance.
\end{itemize}
&
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Difficile de séparer les phases de
conception et de réalisation.
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
\begin{center}
\textbf{Modèle en Spirale}
\end{center}
 &
\begin{itemize}
\item Détermination des objectifs du cycle, analyse des risques et évaluation des alternatives.
\item Développement et vérification de la solution retenue.
\item Revue des résultats et vérification du cycle suivant.
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Donne des indications sur les risques majeurs sans élever le coût.
\item La conception ne doit pas forcément être terminée.
\item Le développement se fait en interaction avec les clients.
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Ce modèle est complexe.
\item La spirale peut être infinie.
\item Il est difficile de définir les objectifs et les points de validation intermédiaires entre les différentes étapes.
\end{itemize}\\

\hline
\begin{center}
\textbf{Modèle par incrément} 
\end{center}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Développement d’un noyau fonctionnel commun à un ensemble d’applications.
\item Développement de ces applications autour du noyau commun.
\item Le recouvrement des différentes phases.
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Chaque développement est moins complexe.
\item Les intégrations sont progressives.
\item Possibilité de livrer et de mettre en service chaque incrément.
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Nécessité d’une bonne planification et une bonne conception.
\item Le coût total du développement du système n’est pas négligeable.
\item Les différentes interfaces doivent être bien définies.
\end{itemize}\\
\hline

  \end{longtable}

\caption{Comparaison entre les méthodologies }
\end{document}
```

How can I resolve that please ?

Comment: please make your example a complete document so people can run it, without knowing the font size or the text width it is hard to suggest changes

Comment: I added a preamble so the code can be run but you must be using a different text size as currently it produces `Overfull \hbox (129.79132pt too wide) in alignment at lines 9--56` please edit the example to be closer to your required layout, then someone can suggest how to change the markup.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edit my code

Comment: after your edit again there is no information about the page size or fonts you are using, you have deleted the `\documentclass`...`\begin{document}` that allows people to run the example and see the problem!

Comment: I'am sorry @DavidCarlisle

Comment: no problem, but if you want help making a table fit a page, you need to tell people how big the page is, and the best way to do that is to provide a complete small document.

Comment: which document class you use? is your text 15 cm wide? please make your document example compilable.

Comment: really you are just making it hard for anyone to help you. have you tried running the code that you posted?  It produces  multiple error messages, starting `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \chapter 
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the sum of the column widths is larger than the text width.

Here's a column type that takes as arguments

1. the numerator of the fraction of the total
2. the denominator of the fraction
3. the number of columns

I use a single `longtable`, with the caption above it. The columns are typeset ragged right, which is better when they're very narrow.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcolumntype{P}[3]{%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}
  p{\dimexpr #1\textwidth/#2 - 2\tabcolsep - #3\arrayrulewidth/\numexpr#3+1}%
}

\newlist{ltitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[ltitemize]{leftmargin=*,label=---}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Présentation Générale}\label{chap1}
\minitoc
\clearpage

\section{Méthodologie du travail}
Suivre une méthodologie de travail est une première assurance 
pour produire des logiciels et des applications de qualité qui 
répondent aux besoins des utilisateurs tout en respectant la 
contrainte du temps en assurant une optimisation du produit.

En effet, il existe plusieurs méthodologies de développement 
parmi lesquelles nous citons les approches classiques caractérisées 
par un processus de développement linéaire dont ses phases 
principales sont recueillir les besoins, définir le produit, 
le développer et le tester avant de le livrer.

Il s'agit ici de prévoir des phases séquentielles et des plans 
détaillés basées sur des exigences stables dès le début du projet.

\subsection{Étude comparative entre ces méthodologies }
Le tableau ci-dessous dégage les différences entre les méthodes 
de développement susmentionnées :

\newpage

\begin{longtable}{
 |
 P{3}{15}{4}
 |
 P{4}{15}{4}
 |
 P{4}{15}{4}
 |
 P{4}{15}{4}
 |
}
\caption{Comparaison entre les méthodologies}\label{tab-comparaison} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{Comparaison entre les méthodologies (continued)} \\
\hline
\endhead
& \textbf{Principes}& \textbf{Points forts} & \textbf{Points faibles} \\
\hline
\begin{center}
\textbf{Modèle en Cascade}
\end{center}
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Les étapes se terminent à des dates précises par la production 
      de documents ou logiciels.
\item Processus linéaire.
\item Les résultats de d’étapes sont examinées attentivement avant 
      de passer à l’étape suivante.
\end{ltitemize}
& 
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Facile à comprendre et à utiliser.
\item Les limites de chaque étape sont visibles.
\item Vision globale du projet au cours de développement.
\end{ltitemize}
& 
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Tous les besoins doivent être bien spécifiés au départ.
\item Difficulté de retour en arrière aux cas des anomalies.
\item L’intégration n’a lieu qu’à la fin du cycle.
\end{ltitemize}\\

\hline
\begin{center}
\textbf{Modèle en V}
\end{center} 
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Le développement de test et du logiciel sont effectuées de manière synchrone.
\end{ltitemize}
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Met l’accent sur les tests et la validation et donc accroît la qualité.
\item Chaque livrable doit être testable.
\item Facile à utiliser et à planifier.
\end{ltitemize}
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Le processus n’est pas itératif.
\item Ne gère pas les activités parallèles.
\end{ltitemize}\\
\hline
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item  Avec toute décomposition doit être décrite la recomposition.
\item Toute description d’un composant est accompagnée de tests qui 
      assurent leurs correspondance.
\end{ltitemize}
&
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Difficile de séparer les phases de
conception et de réalisation.
\end{ltitemize}\\
\hline
\begin{center}
\textbf{Modèle en Spirale}
\end{center}
 &
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Détermination des objectifs du cycle, analyse des risques et 
      évaluation des alternatives.
\item Développement et vérification de la solution retenue.
\item Revue des résultats et vérification du cycle suivant.
\end{ltitemize}
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Donne des indications sur les risques majeurs sans élever le coût.
\item La conception ne doit pas forcément être terminée.
\item Le développement se fait en interaction avec les clients.
\end{ltitemize}
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Ce modèle est complexe.
\item La spirale peut être infinie.
\item Il est difficile de définir les objectifs et les points de 
      validation intermédiaires entre les différentes étapes.
\end{ltitemize}\\

\hline
\begin{center}
\textbf{Modèle par incrément} 
\end{center}
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Développement d’un noyau fonctionnel commun à un ensemble d’applications.
\item Développement de ces applications autour du noyau commun.
\item Le recouvrement des différentes phases.
\end{ltitemize}
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Chaque développement est moins complexe.
\item Les intégrations sont progressives.
\item Possibilité de livrer et de mettre en service chaque incrément.
\end{ltitemize}
&
\begin{ltitemize}
\item Nécessité d’une bonne planification et une bonne conception.
\item Le coût total du développement du système n’est pas négligeable.
\item Les différentes interfaces doivent être bien définies.
\end{ltitemize}\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be more careful with your input:

```
\chapter{ Présentation Générale}
\section{Méthodologie du travail }
```

are incorrect, because spaces count. They should be

```
\chapter{Présentation Générale}
\section{Méthodologie du travail}
```

Don't use `\\` to end paragraphs, but a blank line; `\\` for ending table rows is good.

Answer (score 2):

Use  `xltabular` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlist{nosep,itemsep=0ex,leftmargin=3mm}
\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ |c| *3{>{\RaggedRight}X|} }
    \hline
    & \textbf{Principes }& \textbf{Points forts} & \textbf{Points faibles} \\
    \hline
        \bfseries\raisebox{-12pt}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Modèle en\\ Cascade\end{tabular}}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Les étapes se terminent à des dates précises par la production de documents ou 
        logiciels.
        \item Processus linéaire.
        \item Les résultats de d’étapes sont examinées attentivement avant de passer à l’étape 
        suivante.
    \end{itemize}
    & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Facile à comprendre et à utiliser.
        \item Les limites de chaque étape sont visibles.
        \item Vision globale du projet au cours de développement.
    \end{itemize}
    & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Tous les besoins doivent être bien spécifiés au départ.
        \item Difficulté de retour en arrière aux cas des anomalies.
        \item L’intégration n’a lieu qu’à la fin du cycle.
    \end{itemize}\\
    \hline
        \bfseries\raisebox{-12pt}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Modèle\\ en V\end{tabular}}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Le développement de test et du logiciel sont effectuées de manière synchrone.
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Met l’accent sur les tests et la validation et donc accroît la qualité.
        \item Chaque livrable doit être testable.
        \item Facile à utiliser et à planifier.
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Le processus n’est pas itératif.
        \item Ne gère pas les activités parallèles.
    \end{itemize}\\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]